# Show :$\{B_n^2\}\to0\implies \{B_n\}\to0$.

Tags: real-analysis

How do I show that if $\lim B_n^2=0$ then $\lim B_n=0$?  I tried to use a contradiction where I say suppose $B_n$ does not goes to zero. But then I realize that We cannot say $B_n$ goes to something else to obtain a contradiction since we do not know if $B_n$ converges or not. How should I proceed?

Comment: Should we take $B$ to be a sequence? That is, do you mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n^2=0$ implies $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=0$?

Comment: Yes B is a sequence.

Comment: I've TeXified your title and your post, and tried to clarify your post (since sequences are usually _indexed_); please let me know if I've confused any of the meaning.

Comment: Good exercise; show the converse holds too

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

For $\epsilon^2$,  there exists $N>0$, such that $n>N$, $|B_n^2|< \epsilon^2 $, and hence $|B_n|<\epsilon$

Answer (score 1):

If is sequence:

If  $a_n^2\rightarrow0$, then 
For all $\varepsilon >0$, there exists $N$ belonging to natural number, such that for all $n> N$ implies $|a_n^2|< \varepsilon^2$. 
This implies that $|a_n|^2< \varepsilon^2$, then  $\sqrt{|a_n|^2}<\sqrt{\varepsilon^2}$, then 
$|a_n|<\varepsilon$.

Therefore $a_n\rightarrow0$

Comment: Why can you just set $\epsilon$ squared. By definition, it should just be $\epsilon$. I know it works for sure, but how do you argue this rigorously? I mean, is there a theorem about it>?

Comment: @Kun  $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary.. the definition states that given a $\varepsilon' > 0$ then there exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for $n \geq N$, $|a_n^2| < \varepsilon'$, he just picked $\varepsilon' = \varepsilon^2$